# What does it mean when 'core id' numbering does not have a core numbered 0

Tags: linux, cpu

I encountered some code where counting the number of 0-numbered 'core id's per 'physical id' was used to count the number of hardware threads. Is this logic flawed? Because I encountered this recently even though the logic above had been sound for a long time:

```
> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'core id'
core id         : 2
core id         : 6
core id         : 8
core id         : 12
```